# Ajax call Output into global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to assign the output of ajax call to a global variable so that the output can be used outside the ajax call?

```
var filterarray=new Array();
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: uri,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json",           
            data: {
                input:filtervalue
            },  
            cache: false,
            success : function(response) {
                filterarray = response;
                console.log(response);

                });
            },
            error: function(error) { 
                console.log(error);
            }
            });
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: what is your error? You get an output when you console.log(response)?

Comment: yes i do get error in console.log. but if i put console.log for filterarray after the ajax call it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function getJson(url) {
     return JSON.parse($.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: url,
         dataType: 'json',
         global: false,
         async:false,
         data: {
                filter:value
            },
         success: function(data) {
             return data;
         }
     }).responseText);
    }

Above piece of code solved my issues

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this simple example from [`ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

As you see adding the `context` sets `this` reference within all callbacks:

> The this reference within all callbacks is the object in the context
>   option passed to $.ajax in the settings; if context is not specified,
>   this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

You could also just append your variable to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value to a global variable just like anywhere else in the code.

```
var value;

$.ajax().done(function(responseValue) {
    value = responseValue;
});
```

Although the problem is that this code is asynchronous and you if you try to access the value before call completes, for example right after `$.ajax` block, the value will be undefined. The jQuery `$.ajax` call returns an implementation of Promise, so it's a much better practice to do:

```
var ajaxPromise = $.ajax(...);
// ...

// here you want to access value form ajax call:
ajaxPromise.done(function(value) {
    // do something with value
});
```

The great thing about promises is that you can call `.done` multiple times and it will always resolve with the `value`, even if it was already used before.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxPromise is not defined

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing wrong, but I have tested this code with both jQuery 1.x and 2.x and it works. Therefore I can assure you this code works, given that you have adapted `$.ajax` call to your use case, not just directly copied my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result; 
$.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       async: false, 
       url: url, 
       data: postdata, 
       dataType: "json", 
       success: function (data) { 
       result= data; 
   } });
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
```

Here `async:false` is used to store ajax return value to the global `result` variable.

Let me know these code snippets works or not.

Comment: Its Working for me.Can I see your code ?
can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous. So response may get after the code execution.

```
var filterarray=new Array();
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: uri,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json",           
            data: {
                input:filtervalue
            },  
            cache: false,
            success : function(response) {
                filterarray = response;
                // do what ever you want to do with response here.



                });
            },
            error: function(error) { 
                console.log(error);
            }
            });
    }
```